# NextJs, ReactJs MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, next.js13

I encoutered MissingSchemaError while I was working on a project where I had to make queries on `one to many` relationship and also `.populate()` another model objects.
***Error we are solving in this question:*** `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model`

Comment: Please add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***user.model.ts***

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
 name: string, 
 orders: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Order'
 }]
});
const User = models.User || model('User', UserSchema);
```

***order.model.ts***

```
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
 name: string, 
 user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
    nullable: false,
 }
});
const Order = models.Order || model('Order', OrderSchema);
```

***API calls***

```
import DatabaseConnection from '@/dbConfig/databaseConnection'; // DB connection to DB
import User from '@/models/user.model'; // User model
import Order from '@/models/order.model'; // order model

async function getUsersWithOrders() {
 await DatabaseConnection();
 Order; // <~ very important to first register the Orders model first.
 const users = await User.find(queryParams, {createdAt: 0, updatedAt: 0}).populate('orders');
 return users.json()
}
```

It is very important to register the relationship model you may want to populate with in the query first before you make the query. That is why we import Order model first before we make query to User model.

I hope this helps anyone with error:
`MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model`

Answer (score 0):

Your solutions does indeed work, because you are making sure that the Order model is being triggered/created.

I think you can make it cleaner by just importing the file with the model at the top of your file:

```
import './your-path-to-your-module-with-the-order-model'
```

This way by importing the file containing the referenced model at the top of your page file you are registering the  model before you use it down below inside getServerSideProps.

It looks less weird than just placing the Order like that inside getServerSideProps